# How does SELECT DISTINCT work in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with multiple rows which have a same data.  I used `SELECT DISTINCT` to get a unique row and it works fine.  But when i use `ORDER BY` with `SELECT DISTINCT` it gives me unsorted data.

Can anyone tell me how distinct works?

Based on what criteria it selects the row?

Comment: What are the queries you are trying to run?

Comment: @srivani: Select distinct id from table where id2 =12312 order by time desc.

Comment: I know it's too late but there is no Accepted answer yet so I want to know whether the OP still wants answer for something that is not covered in the given answers?

Answer (score 2):

From your comment earlier, the query you are trying to run is

```
Select distinct id from table where id2 =12312 order by time desc.
```

As I expected, here is your problem. Your select column and order by column are different. Your output rows are ordered by time, but that order doesn't necessarily need to preserved in the id column. Here is an example.

```
id  | id2    | time
-------------------
1   | 12312  | 34
2   | 12312  | 12
3   | 12312  | 48
```

If you run

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id2=12312 ORDER BY time DESC
```

you will get the following result

```
id  | id2    | time
-------------------
2   | 12312  | 12
1   | 12312  | 34
3   | 12312  | 48
```

Now if you select only the id column from this, you will get

```
id
--
2
1
3
```

This is why your results are not sorted.

Comment: What if you have multiple ids (for ex: id = 2 and id =1 occured multiple times) which one it will select by doing desc by time?

Comment: If you run "Select distinct id from table where id2 =12312 order by time desc", the duplicates will be removed. If you run "Select id from table where id2 =12312 order by time desc", the results will contain duplicates. So all occurrences of id will be returned.

Comment: thanks for replying, For example if i want to get recent ids as per time and if i am doing desc by time with distinct id.  Its not working with mysql.  Do you know how distinct works with order by?

Comment: Why don't you update your question with the query that you are running, the output you are expecting and the output you are getting from MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `SELECT DISTINCT` it will give you all the rows, eliminating duplicates from the result set. By "duplicates" I mean rows where all fields have the same values. For example, say you have a table that looks like:

```
 id  |  num
 --------------
 1   |  1 
 2   |  3
 3   |  3
```

`SELECT DISTINCT *` would return all rows above, whereas `SELECT DISTINCT num` would return two rows:

```
num
-----
1
3
```

Note that which row actual row (eg: whether it's row 2 or row 3) it selects is irrelevant, as the result would be indistinguishable.

Finally, `DISTINCT` should **not** affect how `ORDER BY` works.

**Reference: [MySQL `SELECT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)**

Comment: It looks like it does in MYSQL. Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: @Icarus What optimizations it performs is irrelevant, as long as the result set comes back the way you expect it to.

Comment: @NullUserException ఠ_ఠ *In MYSQL* DISTINCT combined with ORDER BY, may or may not work as one would expect. Did you read the link? It seems to depend on how the DISTINCT is transformed internally. Looks to me that you need to do `select (select distinct ...) order by whatever` if you want to make sure that it returns the records in the order you specify. I don't use MYSQL myself, but that's what I gather from reading the MYSQL documentation and other people reporting the same behavior. Did you try it? Do you have a mysql box around that you can use to run a quick test and confirm the behavior?

Comment: @NullUserException ఠ_ఠ in that case Aby is probably going crazy. I will install MySQL tonight and see it with my own eyes, but as I said, Aby is not the first one reporting this behavior.

Comment: Be careful to read the above link.  The order by only isn't guaranteed to work when you are trying to order by a column that isn't being selected.  If you order by something that is in the distinct column list it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe happens when you `ORDER BY` an expression that is not present in the `SELECT` clause. The SQL standard does not allow such a query but MySQL is less strict and allows it.

Let's try an example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT colum1, column2
FROM table1
WHERE ...
ORDER BY column3
```

Let's say the content of the table `table1` is:

```
 id | column1 | column2 | column3
----+---------+---------+---------
  1 | A       | B       | 1
  2 | A       | B       | 5
  3 | X       | Y       | 3
```

Without the `ORDER BY` clause, the above query returns following two records (without `ORDER BY` the order is not guaranteed):

```
 column1 | column2
---------+---------
 A       | B
 X       | Y
```

But with `ORDER BY column3` the order is also not guaranteed.

The `DISTINCT` clause operates on the values of the expressions present in the `SELECT` clause. If row #1 is processed first then (`A`, `B`) is placed in the result set and it is associated with row #1. Then, when row #2 is processed, the values of the `SELECT` expressions produce the record (`A`, `B`) that is already in the result set. Because of `DISTINCT` it is dropped. Row #3 produces (`X`, `Y`) that is also put in the result set. Then, the `ORDER BY column3` clause makes the records be sorted in the result set as (`A`, `B`), (`X`, `Y`).

But if row #2 is processed before row #1 then, following the same logic exposed in the previous paragraph, the records in the result set are sorted as (`X`, `Y`), (`A`, `B`).

There is no rule imposed on the database engine about the order it processes the rows when it runs a query. The database is free to process the rows in any order it consider it's better for performance.

Your query is invalid SQL and the fact that it can return different results using the same input data proves it.